# How to link to iBook?

Tags: iphone, hyperlink, uibutton, ibooks

I am making an app for an author (Patrick Rothfuss) and I would like to be able to link to his book in the iTunes store by clicking a UI button. While I think I can set up the button and everything myself, I can't seem to find out what the link is.

Anyone have any idea how to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think currently its undocumented by Apple, but might be they provide the custom url of iBook in near future.

Comment: well i found one site that found out how to do it but they were in the UK and it didnt work for USA or the book i'm looking to do it for. I emailed iBooks support, they should back to me soon

Comment: figured it out. the ebook has its own ISBN so you put

http: // itunes dot apple dot com/US/book/isbn{insert ISBN-13 of ebook here without dash)

the "US" in there can be changed to whichever ibooks store you want

Answer (score 4):

For a more official approach from Apple, see [iTunes Link Maker](http://itunes.apple.com/linkmaker) to generate links for iBooks as well as apps and everything else.

It seems that it is still limited to making country-specific links. But you can delete the country part and it would still work.

As example:

```
https://itunes.apple.com/us/book/moby-dick/id498469635?mt=11&uo=4
```

Can be also written as (and work on every country):

```
https://itunes.apple.com/book/id498469635?mt=11&uo=4
```

We have deleted book name "moby-dick" (recommended because it's subject to change sometimes) and also the country data "us".